# Simplest secure way to create session cookies

Tags: authentication, web-application, cookies, session-management

Background: I've been using a simple session cookie design for my web app. I have a `users` table, and a `sessions` table that basically looks like this:

```
 id  | user_id | visited_at
-----+---------+-----------
 int | int     | timestamp
```

And a session cookie contains just a session ID, signed with a secret key. I give the cookie an expiration date (but the source of truth is still the timestamp in the DB), and make sure it's secure and HTTP-only.

Then I came across these threads:

- https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=16157002#16159301
- https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=16006394

I think tptacek is basically saying that, instead of storing the signed session ID in the cookie, I can make the `sessions` table like this:

```
 id      | user_id | visited_at
---------+---------+-----------
 varchar | int     | timestamp
```

...where `id` is a randomly generated 16+ byte key encoded as a string, and simply store this string in the session cookie w/o any encryption/signing.

Is this approach secure? Does it have any downsides due to the lack of a signing phase? (I was thinking w/o signing we can't invalidate all sessions by changing the server secret, but then I think we can just delete all the session from the DB since we are not doing stateless authentication anyway.)

**UPDATE:** I think maybe one benefit of the signing approach is that I can save some space in my DB by using an integer primary key. But I'm more interested in the security aspect.

Comment: What you're describing is an everlasting session-id that won't expire until the user manually logs out. If a session-id is stolen and a user deletes it from their browser storage without performing the logout action, the attacker will have unlimited access to that user's account. About the signing part, why not just use something as simple as a [JWT](https://jwt.io/). It's not going to be a Fort Knox but at least its safer than inventing your own session token.

Comment: @ashu 1) The session is made persistent intentionally. As long as the user logs it with the session ID within a TTL, the session timestamp in the DB will be updated and the session will be automatically renewed. 2) I'm not sure how the problem of stolen session ID is specific to this use case. 3) I'm not hand-rolling my signing scheme, just describing how the web framework I use does it. Not using JWT because I need stateful authN and authZ to check permissions in the DB anyway.

Comment: You can use JWT for access control (authz) as well. A part of JWT is an HMAC which is used to validate the claims made by the actual token, i.e. whether it was signed by a recognised entity. In your case, you can store user permissions in the token payload and sign it for the user. When the user returns, you validate the HMAC and then accept whatever claims are provided with the token. If you have a huge list of permissions, the token will be huge which is a huge downside. So you can store the actual claim in a database and pass an identifier with the actual token.